# Problem with \def

Tags: errors, etoolbox

can someone tell me why this works

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{etoolbox}


\newcounter{mylistcounter}
\newcommand{\getnthelement}[2]{
\setcounter{mylistcounter}{1}
\renewcommand*\do[1]{
    \ifnumequal{\value{mylistcounter}}{#1}{##1\listbreak}\relax
    \stepcounter{mylistcounter}}
\dolistloop{#2}}

\def\SerieID{HA}
\listadd\IDlist{HA}
\csgdef{\SerieID.DeckblattDatei}{test (HA)}

\def\SerieID{PR}
\listadd\IDlist{PR}
\csgdef{\SerieID.DeckblattDatei}{test (PR)}



\begin{document}
\def\SerieID{HA}
\csuse{\SerieID.DeckblattDatei}




\end{document}
```

but if I change the \def command to

```
\def\SerieID{\getnthelement{1}{\IDlist}}
```

I get an \endcsname error

Comment: `\getnthelement` contains beside others a \setcounter command and a \renewcommand and so is not expandable and can't be used in as \csuse.

Comment: thank you! Can you tell me how I get this to work right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine `\getnthelement` to take a third argument, for the name of the macro containing the search result.

```
\newcommand{\getnthelement}[3]{%
\setcounter{mylistcounter}{1}%
\renewcommand*\do[1]{%
    \ifnumequal{\value{mylistcounter}}{#1}{\def#3{##1}\listbreak}\relax
    \stepcounter{mylistcounter}}%
\dolistloop{#2}}
```

Note the use of `%` to avoid introducing spurious spaces.

Usage:

```
\getnthelement{1}{\IDlist}\SerieID
\csuse{\SerieID.DeckblattDatei}
```

This solution is fragile, though: The material returned by the search should be expandable, otherwise `\csuse` will again complain. Moreover, if the search fails (because the list is too short), `\SerieID` will be undefined or contain some old value.

Comment: This works fine! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `etoolbox` lists, that are very awkward to get items from, you can use `expl3` sequences.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definelist}{m}
 {
  \seq_new:c { l_gaweiliex_list_#1_seq }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolist}{mm}
 {
  \seq_put_right:cn { l_gaweiliex_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getfromlist}{mm}
 {% #1 = list name
  % #2 = item number
  \seq_item:cn { l_gaweiliex_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definelist{IDlist}
\addtolist{IDlist}{HA}
\csdef{HA.DeckblattDatei}{test (HA)}

\addtolist{IDlist}{PR}
\csdef{PR.DeckblattDatei}{test (PR)}

\begin{document}

\edef\SerieID{\getfromlist{IDlist}{1}}
\csuse{\SerieID.DeckblattDatei}

\edef\SerieID{\getfromlist{IDlist}{2}}
\csuse{\SerieID.DeckblattDatei}

\end{document}
```

[image]